# How can I fix/"unfreeze" my USB ports without rebooting?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I have a USB device (basically a cheap Chinese battery) that is somehow "freezing" my other USB ports. After I plug this device in to my computer no other USB connections will be recognized. Established connections continue to work, but even plugging in my phone afterwards fails to result in charging, let alone device recognition (regardless of the port).

Rebooting seems to fix the issue, however I plug the device in frequently enough that it's rather cumbersome...

I've tried using `devcon remove` (from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/132794/146694)) and oddly enough it just hangs on *any* USB device. I can't get `devcon` to do anything with USB devices other than run `devcon status`.

I took a look at `setupai.dev.log`, and all I get is this:

```
>>>  Section start 2016/10/11 10:47:02.357
      cmd: devcon.exe  restart *ROOT_HUB*
     dvi: Default installer: Enter 10:47:02.362
     dvi:      {Change State}
     dvi:           Device Instance = 'USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&1148BC98&0&0'.
     dvi:           {DICS_PROPCHANGE, DICS_FLAG_CONFIGSPECIFIC}
     dvi:           {Change Device State - USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&1148BC98&0&0}
     dvi:                Restart Device: Config specific
<ins>
```

Plus some garbage characters at the end...

The USB device doesn't do this to any other PCs. My USB drivers are fully updated. I'm a little lost at how to troubleshoot this further.

**Why does `devcon` hang on USB operations and how can I fix it?**

I'm not interested in troubleshooting the device. I have had this happen with other devices as well. I want to know how to troubleshoot the USB root hub/USB drivers.

Comment: Why are you charging a battery through your computer? Going trough an electrical outlet or grounded power strip would likely be quicker.

Comment: What is this "device"?

Comment: How is it unclear what I'm asking?

Comment: @DavidPostill Some sketchy Chinese battery type thing. :) God only knows what it's doing.

Comment: Did you try USBView.exe utility, http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html ? (if you still have any desktop control). It can reset various devices and USB ports, and display connect status and descriptors (if any).